# MVVM-Coordinators with SwiftUI: Problem with 'View' generic protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to update my MVVM-Coordinators pattern to use it with SwiftUI and Combine.

To preserve abstraction, I use a `ScenesFactory` that handle the creation of, well, my scenes like the following:

```
final class ScenesFactory {
    let viewModelsFactory = SceneViewModelsFactory()
}

extension ScenesFactory: SomeFlowScenesFactory {
    func makeSomeScene() -> Scene {
        let someSceneInput = SomeSceneInput()
        let someSceneViewModel = viewModelsFactory.makeSomeSceneViewModel(with: someSceneInput)
        let someSceneView = SomeSceneView()

        someSceneView.viewModel = someSceneViewModel

        return BaseScene(view: someSceneView, viewModel: someSceneViewModel)
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of a my `Scene` protocol:

```
public protocol Scene {
    var view:       some View       { get }
    var viewModel:  ViewModelOutput { get }

    init(view: some View, viewModel: ViewModelOutput)
}
```

The goal here is to be able to use `UIHostingController`to present my `someScene.view` but the compiler throws an error at my `Scene` protocol:

[image]
I thought the point of the `some` keyword was precisely to use generic protocols as a return type.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the point of the some keyword was precisely to use generic protocols as a return type.

Yes, but it seems that it's doesn't work that way in a `protocol` declaration, not really sure why.

But there is a way to fix this, use an `associatedtype` that is constrained to `View`, and the compiler stop complaining.

```swift
public protocol Scene {
    associatedtype Content: View
    var view: Content { get }
}

struct V: Scene {
    var view: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```